# Relating two properties of $e^x$

Tags: exponential-function

1. It is widely known that the derivative of $e^x$ with respect to $x$ is just $e^x$.
2. It is commonly known that the slope of the tangent line of $e^x$ at the point $x=0$ is $1$.

How can I relate 1. with 2. ? That is how can I explain 1. using 2. ? My intuition says that they are related but I can't figure out how!!

In other words: how can I show that $\frac{d}{dx} e^x = e^x$ from the fact that the slope of the tangent line of $e^x$ at the point $x=0$ is $1$. (my feeling tends to see that $1 \times e^x$ = $e^x$ may explain it)

'$e^x$ (where $x$ is the number you think about now)' thanks. =)

Comment: Do you want: as $h\rightarrow0$ $${e^{x+h}-e^x\over h}=e^x\cdot{e^h-1\over h}\longrightarrow e^x\cdot1=e^x?$$

Comment: @David, your comment format is broken.

Comment: Are you asking to find a function, $f$ such that $f'(x) = f(x)$? Your question is confusing.

Comment: no Mr. muffle  my question is:  how can I derive that d/dx e^x = e^x from the fact that the slope of the tangent line of e^x at the point x=0 is 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(x) = e^x$, then $f(0) = e^0 = 1$.

And $f'(0) = e^0 =1$.

And $f''(0) = e^0 =1$.

And $f'''(0) = e^0 =1$.

And ...

But this is just a property of the exponential function.

You can draw no conclusions about $f(x)$ simply from one value of the first derivative.  The fact that $f'(0) = 1$ "looks nice" is just a happy coincidence.

Consider

$$g(x) = \frac{(x+1)^2}{2}.$$

Now, $g'(x) = x+1$, so $g'(0) = 1.$  But clearly $g'(x) \neq g(x)$.  So you cannot say anything about the equality (or inequality) of a function and its derivative simply knowing the value of the derivative at one point.  (Or even many points!)

The exponential function is special because its derivative is the function itself *for all x*.  Showing that it's the same at once point isn't sufficient.

Comment: So if slope of function g(x) for example at a point z for instance is 1 and if g(z)=c then g'(z)=c and g''(z)=c .... True?

Comment: If $g(x) = e^x$, yes.

Comment: But how did you get f'(0)=1 then from 1. ?? I don't understand, if the slope at x=0 is 1 what this means?

Comment: john you used 1. (that d/dx e^x = e^x)in attempt to explain 1. which is circular argument. I'm searching for d/dx e^x=e^x derivation only from 2.

Comment: I used the fact that $f'(x) = f(x)$ if $f(x) = e^x.$  Isn't that your first statement in your question?

Comment: you can't use it since i want to derive it from 2. !!

Comment: Oh, I see. You can't explain the first statement using the second. Consider $f(x) = (x+1)^2/2$. $f'(0) = 1$, but clearly $f'(x) \neq f(x)$.

Comment: But the slope of the tangent line of f(x)=(x+1)^2/2 at point x=0 is 1? sure?

Answer (score 1):

$e^0=1$, and this is the slope of $e^x$ at $x=0$. So...

Answer (score 0):

A proof that $\frac{\text d}{\text dx}e^x=e^x$ might help:

Let $f(x)$ be a function such that $f'(x)=f(x)$.  Then
$$ f(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} $$

For this to be true, it would be really nice for $f(x)$ to satisfy $f(x+h)=f(x)f(h)$ so that we can "factor out" $f(x)$ (there's a bit more reasoning behind this step but let's give intuition credit and move on).  Now, there are only two types of functions that satisfy the functional equation $f(a+b)=f(a)f(b)$ and those are $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)=k^x$ for some $k$ (This is illustrated very nicely in Christopher Small's *Functional Equations and How to Solve Them*, if you're interested.).  We don't want the boring old $0$ function, so let's call our function $f(x)=e^x$ for an arbitrary $e$.  Then we have:

$$\begin{align}e^x&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^xe^h-e^x}{h}\\
1&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^h-1}{h}\tag 1\\
\lim_{h\to0}(1+h)^{1/h}&=e\\
e&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x\end{align}$$
Now, what does $(1)$ require of $e^x$?  That's right!  Your property $2$ (or some version of it), that $e^x-1$ is arbitrarily close to $x$ around $0$.